# How to declare a "struct" variable in yacc

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, yacc

This is my code in yacc:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

%}
%code requires{
struct Node {
char* nodeValue;         
 struct Node* leftOperand;
 struct Node* rightOperand;    
 char* nodeType;
  };
}
%union {

char *string;
Node *node;  <---  error here
}
```

**1.**  I dont know why it showed an error: `unknown type name ‘Node’` even I declared `Node` above. If I put struct before it, it's fine. And I have to put struct before every `Node`.

**2**.If I change `char` into `string` in the `struct` it shows `unknown type name ‘string’` too. it seems I cannot use any type of data other than char, int.

**Edit**: if I write 2 function returning the `Node` type, it means that I have to put struct before them, and it shows `conflicting types` error.

**Update:** I actually compiled my code with C, that's why it showed these errors. Thank you guys for these responses below.

Comment: yacc will produce its output as a `.c` file (at least by default). Perhaps you're compiling it as C instead of C++? If so, you'd need to use `struct Node *node;`. To use `string`, you'd need to `#include <string>` and compile it as C++.

Comment: I just used '#include <string>' and it said 'No such file or directory'

Comment: It sounds like your current problem is more with configuring tools than with writing the code.

Comment: I guess both. please take a look at what I just edited above.

Comment: Can you edit in a minimal version of the offending code and precise text of the error message(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C it needs to be

```
struct Node *node;
```

Comment: Thank you  for your answer. so does it mean for every time using Node *node, I need to put 'struct' before it even I write a function returning 'Node' type? Also, it shows another error 'redefinition of 'struct Node''.

Comment: It might be simplest to put the structure definition into the `%{ ... %}` section of the file.  You might also reduce your workload by adding `typedef struct Node Node;` where you define the structure too.

Comment: TungPham: Yes, if you're writing C, but I recommend @JonathanLeffler's solution.